# Extracting string between two characters in helm

Tags: regex, kubernetes-helm, regex-group

I am trying to extract all strings between `(` and `)` from `values.yaml` in `_helper.tpl`.

In my _helper.tpl

```
{{- define "firstchart.extraction" -}}
{{- regexFindAll "(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))"  .Values.monitor.url -1 -}}
{{- end -}}
```

my `values.yaml` file

```
monitor:
   url: "(zone-base-url)/google.com/(some-random-text)"
```

so i want to extract `zone-base-url` and `some-random-text`. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the regex library is RE2 that does not support lookarounds of any type.
That means, you need to "convert" non-consuming lookarounds into consuming patterns, still keeping the capturing group in between the `\(` and `\)` delimiters:

```
{{- regexFindAll "\\((.*?)\\)"  .Values.monitor.url -1 -}}
```

Or,

```
{{- regexFindAll "\\(([^()]*)\\)"  .Values.monitor.url -1 -}}
```

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (`[^()]*` matches zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` chars)
- `\)` - a `)` char

The `-1` argument extracts just the Group 1 contents.

A literal backslash in the pattern must be doubled to represent a literal backslash.

Comment: Thanks. But how to remove the delimiters `(` and `)` from output

Comment: @dark_prince The -1 argument extracts just the Group 1 contents.